# Angular formly - assign key to property in array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angular-formly

I am working on list of languages and levels of proficiency. This would be a array of objects:

```
languages : [ 
  { name : 'English', level : 'native' },
  { name : 'Spanish', level : 'good' }
]
```

So I have such definitions of fields:

```
{
    className       : 'col-xs-4',
    type                : 'ui-select', 
    key             : 'languages[' + index + '].name',
    templateOptions : {
           label                : 'Some label',
           options          : [ ... data there ... ],
           required         : true
    }
},
{

    className       : 'col-xs-8 btn-radio-language',
    type                : 'btn-radio',
    key             : 'languages[' + index + '].level',
    templateOptions : {
        label           : 'Proficiency',
        options         : ... data for native, good, so so ...
    }
}
```

Those definition would repeat several times with respect of index.
However instead of array languages being addressed with values series of properties in model like:

```
"languages[0].level": "native",
"languages[1].level": "advanced",
"languages[0].name": "German"
```

have been created...

How I can point to languages array in model ?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood it correctly you could map your data with `languages.map(function(language) {...})`.

Please have a look at the demo below or at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/ne39tyqq/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['formly', 'formlyBootstrap'])
  .controller('MainController', function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.model = {};
    var languages = [ 
      { name : 'English', level : 'native' },
      { name : 'Spanish', level : 'good' }
    ];
    
    var createOptionTmpl = function(value) {
      return {
        name: value,
        value: value
      };
    };
    
    /*
    console.log(languages.map(function(lang) {
         return {
           name: lang.level,
            value: lang.level
          };
        }));*/
        
    vm.fields = [{
      className: 'col-xs-4',
      type: 'select',
      key: 'languages.name',
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Some label',
        options: languages.map(function(lang) {
         return createOptionTmpl(lang.name);
        }), //[...data there...],
        required: true
      }
    }, {

      className: 'col-xs-8 btn-radio-language',
      type: 'radio',
      key: 'languages.level',
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Proficiency',
        options: languages.map(function(lang) {
         return createOptionTmpl(lang.level);
        })
      }
    }];
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/api-check/7.5.5/api-check.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-formly/7.3.9/formly.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-formly-templates-bootstrap/6.2.0/angular-formly-templates-bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="MainController as vm">
  <form ng-submit="vm.onSubmit()">
    <formly-form model="vm.model" fields="vm.fields"></formly-form>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">
      submit
    </button>
  </form>

  {{vm.model}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response - however I was looking for addressing model values that intended to be array, You are showing me how to deal with options for select or radio - this is not exactly what I was asking for